# HTML Form Field Array to PHP Post using Javascript & AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have the code below and I'm doing it wrong. I need it to get the items from the form field 'standardname[]' and send it to PHP via ajax.

Here is my code:

```
function standardSave() {
        //get the data from the form field-its a text input array
        var names=document.getElementsByName('standardname[]');
        
        //for each item in the array
        for(key=0; key < names.length; key++)  {        
            
            //combine the items in this 'toadd' array
            var toadd = { "standard[key]" : "names[key].value" };
        
        //send to PHP via ajax
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "draftsave.php",
            data: toadd,
            success: function(result) {
            }
        });
        
        //empty the var
        var toadd = [];
    };
    </script>
```

I think I just need help with this line:

```
var toadd = { "standard[key]" : "names[key].value" };
```

I just don't know what the correct method is.

Thanks!

Comment: Any reason you are not using https://api.jquery.com/serialize/ ?

Comment: @CBroe No, just came up with this way after looking at various ways to do it.

Comment: `"names[key].value"` — Quotes are for string literals. Don’t put quotes around expressions.

Comment: Do you really want to make a separate Ajax request for each input?

Comment: @Quentin no, I just want a single output of the data to php.

Answer (score -1):

```
form action="javascript:void(0)" onsubmit="standardSave()">

        <input type="text" name="standardname[]">
        <input type="text" name="standardname[]">
        <input type="text" name="standardname[]">
        <input type="text" name="standardname[]">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>

    </form>
    <script>
        function standardSave() {
            console.log('i got called')
            //get the data from the form field-its a text input array
            var names=document.getElementsByName('standardname[]');
            
            //for each item in the array
            for(key=0; key < names.length; key++)  {        
                    
                //combine the items in this 'toadd' array
                var toadd = { "standard[]" : names[key].value };
                console.log("key: ", key)
                console.log(toadd)
                    

                //send to PHP via ajax
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: "draftsave.php",
                    data: toadd,
                    success: function(result) {
                        console.log('i should be working now bro')
                    }
                });
                
                //empty the var
                var toadd = [];
            };
        }
    </script>
```

let me know if this works. I can't put "standard[key]" in key of toadd array for some reason. i want key to be dynamically the one you provide in the for loop. also i don't know what standard is, but I'm assuming it's a string. you can look up other methods for it or change your implementation of the toadd array key.

anyways this should work. I checked it and this is sending values to the PHP file one by one, assuming each input field has name of "standardname[]"

Comment: Thanks. On my php page, I want to add all of the output to an array. Is there any way to gather the results first, then send them in a single ajax to the php variable? Thanks.